# summation of sine angle in AP

Tags: trigonometry, summation

If $x = \frac{\pi}{5}$ & the value of
$y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(\sqrt{(1+cos2x)}+\sqrt{(1+cos4x)}+\sqrt{(1+cos6x)}+...+\sqrt{(1+cos12x)})$ can be written as $\frac{5}{4}(\sqrt{p}+q^2)$, then what will be the value of $\frac{5}{6} [p + q^2]$?

My approach is as follow

$y = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\sqrt {1 + \cos 2x}  + \sqrt {1 + \cos 4x}  + ... + \sqrt {1 + \cos 12x} } \right) \Rightarrow y = \frac{1}{{\sqrt 2 }}\left( {\sqrt {2\left( {{{\sin }^2}x} \right)}  + \sqrt {2\left( {{{\sin }^2}2x} \right)}  + ... + \sqrt {2\left( {{{\sin }^2}6x} \right)} } \right)$

$y = \left( {\left| {\sin x} \right| + \left| {\sin 2x} \right| + \left| {\sin 3x} \right| + ... + \left| {\sin 6x} \right|} \right)$

$x = \frac{\pi }{5},y = \left( {\left| {\sin \frac{\pi }{5}} \right| + \left| {\sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5}} \right| + \left| {\sin \frac{{3\pi }}{5}} \right| + ... + \left| {\sin \frac{{6\pi }}{5}} \right|} \right)$

$y = \left( {\sin \frac{\pi }{5} + \sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5} + \sin \frac{{3\pi }}{5} + ...\sin \frac{{5\pi }}{5} - \sin \frac{{6\pi }}{5}} \right) \Rightarrow y = \left( {\sin \frac{\pi }{5} + \sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5} + \sin \left( {\pi  - \frac{{2\pi }}{5}} \right) + \sin \left( {\pi  - \frac{\pi }{5}} \right) + 0 - \sin \left( {\pi  + \frac{\pi }{5}} \right)} \right)$

$y = \left( {\sin \frac{\pi }{5} + \sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5} + \sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5} + \sin \frac{\pi }{5} + 0 + \sin \frac{\pi }{5}} \right) \Rightarrow y = \left( {3\sin \frac{\pi }{5} + 2\sin \frac{{2\pi }}{5}} \right)$

$y = \left( {3\sin \frac{\pi }{5} + 4\sin \frac{\pi }{5}\cos \frac{\pi }{5}} \right) = \sin \frac{\pi }{5}\left( {3 + 4\cos \frac{\pi }{5}} \right)$

$\cos \frac{\pi }{5} = \frac{{\sqrt 5  + 1}}{4};\sin \frac{\pi }{5} = \frac{{\sqrt {10 - 2\sqrt 5 } }}{4}$

$y = \frac{{\sqrt {10 - 2\sqrt 5 } }}{4}\left( {3 + 4 \times \frac{{\sqrt 5  + 1}}{4}} \right) = \frac{{\sqrt {10 - 2\sqrt 5 } }}{4}\left( {\sqrt 5  + 4} \right)$

Not able to proceed further

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All would have been well, if you correctly used $$1+\cos 2x=2\cos^2x$$

(There are lots of cancelling terms. Then the only thing you have to remember to get the answer is $\cos\frac{\pi}{5}=\frac{\sqrt5+1}4.$)

Comment: Thanks for pointing this error I made a mistake, I knew the formula but some time people do make silly error

Comment: I wanted to point out this as a comment. But I don't have enough reputation to comment on others' posts.